# Template specialization type lists without macros?

Tags: c++, templates

So given a function f is there way to define specific behaviors for certain individual non related classes, without some macro-foo

e.g. a replacement / way of accomplishing the same thing as :

```
//p for param

template<typename T> 
T f(T p){ // some default op}; 

template<>
T f<float>(T p)
{ return 2*p; }

template<>
T f<double>(T p)
{ return 2*p; }

template<>
T f<int>(T p)
{ return 2*p; }

template<>
T f<std::string>(T p)
{ //return p copies of the string appended together; }

template<>
T f<std::vector>(T p)
{ //return the vector's element's copied}

// etc
```

No I would not like normal overloads.
ideally something like 
template

```
if T in [int, float, double]
T f(T p) { return 2*p; }
```

else // define a default other behavior. which you could do in python.

Anyway to make a decision based on the class of T? A possible solution I can think of which is very ... not pretty would be using typeid and demangling.

say for some reason you had a super generic function and some 15 different classes, writing that all using overloading would not be pretty.

Comment: A replacement without macros for something that doesn't have any macros?

Comment: Is there a reason to have a default implementation that does nothing? (BTW, if that is ever called you will get undefined behavior, you promised to return a `T` and you are not returning anything!)

Comment: You might think you want template specializations, but you're wrong.  You want non-template overloads with the same name as the function template.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf: Well, most of the specializations do the same thing, if that is the case, you can just nail that into the base template and provide only specializations for the ones that differ. Other than that, you could use a typelist to provide multiple member functions 'f' in a utility class for a fixed set of overloads. It will make the code ugly, but it won't contain macros (admitedly it will look even worse than with macros... but heck the requirements are *no macros*!)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas ideally given a set of classes of functions $S$, define default a default return value for elements $S_i$, ehh well know any way to give a macro class scope then? haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to make a list of types which should be handled differently than all other types?

If that is the case make a list of the desired types and use a meta function to determine if T is in your list of types returning true or false.

then use enable_if to switch between function implementations.

```
#include <boost\mpl\vector.hpp>
#include <boost\mpl\contains.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::vector<char,int,unsigned,long,unsigned long> types;
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<boost::mpl::contains<types,T>::value, T>::type 
    foo(T t) 
{
    std::cout << "special foo\n";
    return t;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<boost::mpl::not_<boost::mpl::contains<types,T>>::type::value, T>::type 
    foo(T t) 
{
    std::cout << "normal foo\n";
    return t;
}
void main()
{
    foo(1);   //calls special foo because int is in the list
    foo(1.1); //calls normal foo because float is not in the list
}
```

**Update:** boost.MPL is outdated, if you have C++11 support use [brigand](https://github.com/edouarda/brigand)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need rather normal (non template) function overloads:

```
float f(float p)
{ return 2*p; }

double f(double p)
{ return 2*p; }

int f(int p)
{ return 2*p; }

std::string f(std::string p)
{ //return p copies of the string appended together; }

std::vector f(std::vector p)
{ //return the vector's element's copied}
```